# How can we limit recursive calls in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I've got a problem with my code, which is the following:

```
import Data.List

splitat _ [] = ([],[])
splitat element (head:tail)
  | element == head = ([],(head:tail))
  | otherwise = ([head]++fst(splitat element tail), snd(splitat element tail))
```

It splits a list at 'element', then combining the left and right sublist into a tuple.
However, in the third line, the 'splitat element tail' command is called twice, once through 'fst' and once through 'snd'. Is there a way to evaluate this term only 1 time to keep the recursion tree narrow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[head] ++ ...`? Use `head : ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**. You can make use of a `let` expression, or a `where` clause. For example:

```
splitat :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitat _ [] = ([],[])
splitat x' xa@(x:xs) | x == x' = ([], xa)
                     | otherwise = (x:ys1, ys2)
    where (ys1, ys2) = splitat x' xs
```

> **Note**: please do *not* use [**`head :: [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head) or [**`tail :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head) or other functions that are defined as variables, since these will *shadow* the existing binding. It makes it harder to reason about the code, since a person might think that `head` and `tail` refer to these functions, and not the variables.

Comment: Though arguably, better would be if `head` and `tail` were purged from `base` and all libraries that use them...

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I agree with that, since these are unsafe functions :).

Comment: Hear, here.  They are perfectly good variable/function names too, always cluttering up my namespace.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Control.Arrow.first` (or `Data.Bifunctor.first`; the `arrow` library ships with GHC, while I don't recall if you need to install `bifunctor` first or not):

```
splitat _ [] = ([],[])
splitAt e lst@(h:t) | e == h = ([], lst)
                    | otherwise = first (h:) (splitAt e t)
```

Comment: [`Data.Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) is in `base` now; it was added in GHC 7.10, if I’m reading my version numbers right (`base` 4.8.0.0).